# Sumar todos los campos de varios registros correspondientes a una columna MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

¿Cómo puedo sumar todos los campos que corresponden a una columna en una tabla?

Ejemplo:

```
| ID  | Cantidad |
------------------
| 1   | 200      |
| 2   | 150      |
| 3   | 60       |
```

¿Cómo puedo sumar todos los campos de "Cantidad"? Es decir, (200 + 150 + 60).

Pueden empezar directamente por la búsqueda. Ta tengo la conexión hecha.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: `select sum(cantidad) from table`

Comment: Puedes utilizar Sum, por ejejmplo  "select sum(cantidad) from tu_tabla;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(MYSQL) Tu SQL debería quedar así:

```
Select sum(cantidad) from _nombreTabla_;
```

De esa forma podrás sumar todos los REGISTROS O FILAS (no "campos", no se llaman "campos") de una tabla, siempre y cuando, obviamente, sean valores numéricos.

[Documentación y ejemplos AQUÍ](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)